# window.screen.width gives height of screen on iPhone/iPad in ladscape mode

Tags: javascript, iphone, responsive-design, screen

I'm trying to determine the current width of the screen visiting a page and am trying `window.screen.width` which works fine in the browser, in chrome emulator and in a Samsung phone I've tried. But if I do the same from an actual iPhone or iPad, the width will show as height when the device is in landscape mode. Here is a screen dump of how it looks on the site [mydevice.io](http://mydevice.io/)

- [In portrait mode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oin0uf5o590w41j/2015-12-15%2013.54.51.png?dl=0) (where all is good)
- [In landscape mode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbf6pg1t1xi6yyj/2015-12-15%2013.55.14.png?dl=0), where things are odd

Why is the sizes wrong and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`screen.width` on most Opera and Android browsers behave as you would expect, and will return the values for portrait and landscape.

iOS returns the dimensions of the screen, but doesn't care about portrait and landscape orientation of the content.

`window.outerWidth` or `window.innerWidth` is more reliable when it comes to phones, but does not work as well with height (`window.outerHeight`).